# How to replace dynamic regex with null value?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and I like to replace dynamic regex by "null" expression:
For example replace regex "[1-9]|\d{2,} or \w{2/}" by null value:

```
list_regex=["num=([1-9]|\d{2,})","<urn:rental>\w{2,}</urn:rental>"]
```

How can I do this dynamically without using "replace"?
The result must be like this :

```
 list_regex=["num=null","<urn:rental>null</urn:rental>"]
```

Can you help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `list_regex[0] = "num=null"`?

Comment: I don't know in what context this is happening but be warned that "regex injection" can be used to DoS a website: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your regexes such that they can be `.format`'d into

```py
list_regex = [r"num={}", r"<urn:rental>{}</urn:rental>"]

replacement_options = {
    "name1": (r"([1-9]|\d{2,})", r"\w{2,}"),
    "nulls": ("null", "null"),
}

def test_many(inputs_list, list_regex, replacement_options):
    for name, replacers in replacement_options.items():
        match_group = []
        for index, replacer in enumerate(replacers):
            match = re.match(list_regex[index].format(replacer), inputs_list[index])
            if not match:  # optional test to break out faster
                break  # continue with next (name, replacer)
            match_group.append(match)
        if all(match_group):
            return name, match_group
    raise ValueError("never matched!")
```

you could also default to filling each field with `null`

Comment: Thank you for your help